# stored procedure not updating records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a c# function calling a SQL Server stored procedure with input parameters.  The stored procedure works fine when executed directly through SQL Server Management Studio, so I believe the issue must be on the c# side, however I cannot figure it out for the life of me.  I've already searched through all the previous times this issue has arisen for others and I have been unable to find a solution.  If it ultimately can't be determined what's wrong, some tips on debugging would be very much appreciated as I'm not too good at more advanced troubleshooting.

here is the c# function:

```
protected void UpdateProfile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeHubDBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateProfile", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userloggedin.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = first_name.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = last_name.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@MiddleInitial", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = middle_initial.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Assignment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl_assignment.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rank", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rank.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Star", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = star.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contact_phone.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = phone_type.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Shift", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddl_shift.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModifyDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModifiedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userloggedin.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "active";

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Response.Write("Profile updated successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Profile update error:  " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the sql server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spUpdateProfile

@UserId         VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,

@FirstName      VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@LastName       VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@MiddleInitial  VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@Assignment     VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@Rank           VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@Star           VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,

@ContactPhone   VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@PhoneType      VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@Email          VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@Shift          VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,

@ModifyDate     VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@ModifiedBy     VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    ,
@StatusId       VARCHAR(200)    =   NULL    

AS
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.users
    SET
        first_name          =   @FirstName          ,
        last_name           =   @LastName           ,
        middle_initial      =   @MiddleInitial      ,
        assignment          =   @Assignment         ,
        user_rank           =   @Rank               ,
        user_star           =   @Star               ,
        contact_phone       =   @ContactPhone       ,
        phone_type          =   @PhoneType          ,
        email               =   @Email              ,
        regular_shift       =   @Shift              ,
        modify_date         =   @ModifyDate         ,
        modified_by         =   @ModifiedBy         ,
        status_id           =   @StatusId           
    WHERE
        user_id             =   @UserId
END
```

Comment: First step: Make sure the user_id you are targeting from your code exists.

Comment: you try opening the connection first then creating the command.

Comment: Done.  I have a separate function that runs on page_load, calling a stored procedure that pulls the user_id based on the session_id, and then populates a hidden textbox (id = userloggedin) with the user_id.  I have another function that runs using userloggedin.Text and it runs without any issues, so I'm sure this isn't the issue

Comment: the function doesn't return any error messages

Comment: @DotnayTupperson : are you saying I should move the SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand to be outside the try/catch ?

Comment: Do you hit the success message? And what is returned by ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: @GPicazo : ExecuteNonQuery returns a '1' and the success message displays properly.

Comment: @Steve : there is a function that fires properly on page_load to select the user_id, using the session_id.  This function uses the same connection string and works properly.  I've tried copying/pasting the connection string to be sure and it hasn't helped.

Comment: Which are the values which are not getting updated ? Or all values don't update ?

Comment: @Partha : The only values that update correctly are
'@ModifyDate'
'@ModifiedBy' and
'@Satus_Id'.

This is a user profile page that populates with profile data on page_load.  It's possible that the function is reading the values that are initially populating the textboxes on page_load and the newly input values are not being transfered into the parameters, but I'm not sure how to check/fix that.

Comment: Use if(!Page.ispostback){//your function} on page_load

Comment: @Partha:  that worked!  I wrapped the function within page_load with if(!Page.ispostback) {}.  works as expected now.

I'll read the MSDN on the topic, but is there a very quick explanation as to why it didn't work initially?

Comment: The syntax I mentioned means to execute your function only when the page loads 1st time and not for postbacks. When you change values in textboxes and click a button, postback occurs at which time the values are changed to initial value as the function executes again. Now your function executes only when the page loads 1st time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partha answered the question in the comments section under the original post.

Issue was that I had a function which populated textboxes on the page with user data on page_load.  Every time the update function ran, the page posted back to the server and the page_load event fired again, repopulating the textboxes with the original data, and then using that data to update the record in my table.

Adding if(!Page.ispostback){function} around the function within the pag_load event solved the issue by only populating those fields if the page was loaded the first time, and not on refreshes/postbacks

Answer (score 1):

Your description is missing a key factor in troubleshooting code. What exactly is the error? If you cant identify the error, you can't really begin to troubleshoot it.

Put a break point on your catch and try to run it. When it stops at that break point, take a look at the exception and the exception's stack trace. It will usually tell you why you failed. Also, you can put a break point at the top of the procedure then mouse over each of the variables and see if they are all present. Maybe one is missing or has an incorrect data type.